# pandas: groupby multiple columns. How to get all combinations?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe describing persons, where age_range has been computed from the age column

```
   age  gender group    age_range
0   46  F      1       >= 30 and < 60
1   50  F      1       >= 30 and < 60
2   63  F      2       >= 60
3   65  F      2       >= 60
4   34  F      1       >= 30 and < 60
5   42  F      2       >= 30 and < 60
6   55  F      1       >= 30 and < 60
7   57  M      1       >= 30 and < 60
```

From there, I would like a table giving for each group, all age_ranges and the number of persons from the group and the age_range, even for empty bins (no person < 30 in any of the two groups and all members of group 1 are in >= 30 and < 60).

How could I get something like the following?

```
    group   age_range       count
0   1       < 30            0
1   1       >= 30 and < 60  5
2   1       >= 60           0
3   2       < 30            0
4   2       >= 30 and < 60  1
5   2       >= 60           2
```

I tried multiple groupby options but never managed to get a complete table.

Answer (score 3):

To get the non-zero counts:

```
g = df.groupby(['group','age_range']).size().to_frame('count').reset_index()
```

Then, you'll want a dummy table of all the group and age range combinations:

```
from itertools import product
combs = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['group'], df['age_range'])), 
                     columns=['group', 'age_range'])
```

Merge (SQL join) `g` with this, and replace the NaNs with zeros:

```
result = g.merge(combs, how = 'right').fillna(0)
```

A one-liner solution:

```
df.groupby(['group','age_range']).size().to_frame('count').reindex(MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), df['age_range'].unique()], fill_value = 0))
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot. That's what I needed. To construct the dummy table, I had to start with the list of possible values since not all of them are present in the actual dataframe.

Comment: instead of the join, you could do a [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with a [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_product)

Comment: Actually, that would probably be faster: `df.groupby(['group','age_range']).size().to_frame('count').reindex(MultiIndex.from_product([df['group'].unique(), df['age_range'].unique()]))`